# Bootstrap auto completion in PhpStorm with CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have linked Bootstrap correctly in my html file within PhpStorm but I do not get any code completions when typing `jumbotron` for example.

how do I fix that?

Comment: Are you asking why your IDE doesn't show suggestions when you start typing?

Comment: Linking to CDN will not give you any code completion -- file MUST be local (IDE should be able to read and index it). So .. just download such .css file and place anywhere in your project -- it should pick it up. If not -- you will have to use link to the local version

Comment: What to do, is to install your favorite libraries in a common mass via NPM, and add them as libraries in a global scope, even if you use the CDN they will automatically complete

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#viewingLibsAssociatedWithFile